# order by case in sql 2005 server

Tags: mysql, sql

One of the column in my table like this:

```
Symbol  
586fast                
urgent         
243late  
296fast  
122late   
155fast
```

I need urgent in first then records with fast order asc then records with late order asc like this:

```
urgent  
586fast  
296fast  
155fast  
243late   
122late
```

I am getting urgent in first row,records with fast and late but they are not in asc order

```
    ORDER BY CASE 
when Symbol like '%FUT' then 1 
when Symbol like '%CE' then 2 
when Symbol like '%PE' then 3 
else 4 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After ordering using case statement provide further ordering by Symbol column itself

```
ORDER BY CASE 
when Symbol like '%FUT' then 1 
when Symbol like '%CE' then 2 
when Symbol like '%PE' then 3 
else 4 end, Symbol asc
```